# Where can i download SQL server express 2008 from?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have windows xp (sp3, i think). I tried to download the sql express version, but it says that it is invalid win32 application.

```
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=58ce885d-508b-45c8-9fd3-118edd8e6fff&displaylang=en
```

I have been trying to find a version that will work for the last hour, but i cant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32 bit is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPDBMT32/enus/)
64 bit is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPDBMT64/enus/)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Make sure you select the right version (32 or 64 bit)

Comment: it wont let me pass through the setup support rules..why. ? it says windows power shell is not installed

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Diogo: The question was "Where can i download SQL server express 2008 from?" What other details, besides the link, could possibly be included in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Download SQL server express from here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=1695